# Newly added field does not update unless made mandatory in Yii 1.1

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

Fellow Yii-ites,

I added a new date field at the DB table after the model and form code were generated. The value from this field is not getting persisted in the DB. Tried both create and update. However, it works if the field is made "required" in the model class. It is a nullable field in the DB and I do not want to force it be "required" in the model class.

In Model class function rules (check the field `enrolby_date`):

```
return array(
        array('level, start_date, court_type, org_id', 'required'),
        array('level, court_type, org_id, status, no_courts', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('location, referee', 'length', 'max'=>45),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, location, level, start_date, enrolby_date, referee, court_type, org_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
```

The property is not in the "required" list.

In `_form.php` view:

```
<tr><td>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'enrolby_date'); ?>
        </td><td><?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array('name'=>'enrolby_date',
                'attribute'=>'enrolby_date',
                'model'=>$model,
                'options'=>array('showAnim'=>'fold', 'dateFormat'=> 'yy-mm-dd'),
            ));
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'enrolby_date'); ?>
    </td></tr>
```

Note that I tried this without the DatePicker widget, the behaviour is the same.

DB Table definition goes like this -

```
mysql> desc tour;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| location     | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| level        | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| enrolby_date | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| referee      | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| court_type   | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status       | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| org_id       | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| no_courts    | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Additional info: The form shows the date value in the update action, if I populate the field in the DB table using a SQL UPDATE. There is no issue with the field names and binding because it works fine if made "required".

What seems to be the problem here?

Cheers.
Mukul

**Update:** Here's another hint. The problem disappears if I add the following line of code in the `rules()` function.

`array('start_date, enrolby_date', 'type', 'type' => 'date', 'message' => '{attribute}: is not a date!', 'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'),`

It seems that model need some sort of evidence that the field exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `array('name'=>'enrolby_date')`. When you generate form, yii generates `<input type="text" name="ModelName['fieldName']">`. But if you change `name` attribute of the field and assign it's `name` manually, yii does not set it automatically. I think you have two solutions, first you can change name into it:  `array('name'=>'YourModelName[enrolby_date]')`.

Second solution: you can assign "enrolby_date" manually in the controller in this way:

```
$model->enrolby_date = $_POST['enrolby_date'];
```

Comment: @hamid, the code generation does not seem to be the problem. The field is bound to the model anyway (just like the other fields). Following is the HTML that is generated.
`<label for="Tour_enrolby_date">Enrol by Date</label>   </td><td><input id="enrolby_date" name="Tour[enrolby_date]" type="text" value="2015-04-14" />`. Moreover why would it work if the field is made 'required'?